# How to prove that the union of two subspaces must be subsets of each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Union of two vector subspaces not a subspace?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71872/union-of-two-vector-subspaces-not-a-subspace)

> $U,W\subseteq V$ are subspaces.
>
> Prove that in order for $U \cup W$ to be a subspace as well, either $U\subseteq W$ or $W\subseteq U$

Can anyone please give me a lead on this ?

Comment: Maybe think of the geometry of it. Pick $u\in U$ and $w\in W$ with $u\not\in W$ and $w\not\in U$; you can do this only if neither of $U$ and $W$ is a subspace of the other.  Then consider $u+w$. If $U\cup W$ were a subspace, $u+w \in U\cup W$, but it isn't.

Comment: See [this answer of Gerry Myerson's](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/71879/3701).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure: supppose that $U$ is not contained in $W$ and $W$ is not contained in $U$.  Let $x \in U \setminus W$, $y \in W \setminus U$, and consider $x+y$.

Note that this argument works for subgroups of an arbitrary group.

Answer (score 3):

The condition that $U\not\subseteq W$ and $W\not\subseteq U$ is equivalent to the statement that there are $v_1\in U\setminus W$ and $v_2\in W\setminus U$, from which the result easily follows.