# Subspaces: intersection and union

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are subspaces of the vector space $\Bbb{R}^n$. 
    Show that $H=A \cap B$ is also a subspace of the vector space $\Bbb{R}^n$.
    Show by construction of the example that $R=A \cup B$ is not always a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Duplicate of various posts, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/71872/264) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/298955/264) for example.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298955/intersection-and-union-of-subspaces?rq=1
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71872/union-of-two-vector-subspaces-not-a-subspace?lq=1
related (...what @ZevChonoles said)

Comment: When I was a math student problems like show that *this* is a *that* frustrated my fellow students.  I liked them.  To solve them, look up the definition of a *that*.  Verify all the elements of the definition.  It tests well that you understand the definition of a *that*.  In this case, the challenge is closure: if you add two elements you get another element.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is almost trivial: you only have to understand the very definitions. For the second, as counter example, take

$$A:=Span\left\{\;\binom{1}{0}\;\right\}\;,\;\;B:=Span\left\{\;\binom{1}{1}\;\right\}\;,\;\;A,B\subset \Bbb R^2$$

Take now, for example

$$u:=\binom{1}{0}\;,\;\;v:=\binom{1}{1}$$

and assume $\, A\cup B\,$ is a subspace, but then were does $\,u+v\,$ belong...?

**Added:** Suppose

$$u+v=a\in A\implies v=a-u\in A\ldots\text{contradiction, since it's easy to check that}\;\;v\notin A$$

then it must be that

$$u+v=b\in B\implies u=b-v\in B\ldots\text{again contradiction because}\;\; u\notin B\;!$$

Comment: I understand that u+v should be contained in both A and B if their union was a subspace. But i struggle in formulating this in a correct mathematical manner.

Comment: @user71671, check what I added to my answer which is the heart of the proof that $\,A\cup B\,$ isn't a subspace **unless** $\,A\subset B\;\;or\;\;B\subset A\,$