# Proving a biconditional statement with an or

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I want to prove a theorem in geometry of the form $p \iff q \vee r$. My plan is to prove:

1. $q \implies p$ as well as $r \implies p$
2. $p \text{ and } \lnot q \implies r$

Can I get someone to verify that I haven't sidetracked in my logic?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: This might help btw: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396253/how-to-prove-or-statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your planned approach is sound.

Answer (score 1):

The following calculation shows that your logic is fine:
\begin{align}
& p \iff q \lor r \\
\iff & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"split $\iff$ into both directions"} \\
& (p \implies q \lor r) \;\land\; (q \lor r \implies p) \\
\iff & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"expand $\implies$, twice; use De Morgan in RHS"} \\
& (\lnot p \lor q \lor r) \;\land\; ((\lnot q \land \lnot r) \lor p) \\
\iff & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"distribute $\lor$ over $\land$ in RHS"} \\
& (\lnot p \lor q \lor r) \;\land\; (\lnot q \lor p) \;\land\; (\lnot r \lor p) \\
\iff & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"introduce $\implies$ again, three times, using De Morgan for the first time"} \\
& (p \land \lnot q \implies r) \;\land\; (q \implies p) \;\land\; (r \implies p) \\
\end{align}

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you.