# Proving an "OR" statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If one wants to proof $P\vee Q$, is it sufficient to proof $\lnot P \rightarrow Q$? Because it makes intuitively more sense to me that $P\vee Q$ would be logically equivalent with $(\lnot P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (\lnot Q \rightarrow P)$.

Comment: Related: [How to prove or statements](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396253/how-to-prove-or-statements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in fact equivalent to $\lnot P\rightarrow Q$, which is also equivalent to $\lnot Q\rightarrow P$. So yes, it is indeed sufficient. However, in a formal logic system you should probably prove this using whatever axioms/rules of deduction you have.

Comment: How stupid of me not to think of that. Thanks.