# Difference between sum of vector spaces and union of subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between summing two subspaces and making ther union. My book says that the sum of two subspace is also a subspace, but I've found [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71872/union-of-two-vector-subspaces-not-a-subspace) that shows that the union of a subspace is not always a subspace. So, what's the difference?

Comment: Do you know the definition of sum of two subspaces of a vector space?

Comment: @GitGud $U + V = \{u+v|u\in U, v \in V\}$

Comment: Can you prove that $U\cup V\subseteq U+V$ and can you see that the other inclusion doesn't hold a priori?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$V= \mathbb{R}^2, W_1=\langle(0,1)\rangle, W_2=\langle(1,0)\rangle$

Then the union of $W_1$ and $W_2$ is the union of $x$ axis and $y$ axis.

But the sum of them, is all possible combinations of two elements in $W_1,W_2$, thus the sum is $V$, because we can write every element in $V$ as $(x,y)=x(1,0)+y(0,1)$.