# Showing $(U\cap U_1)+(U\cap U_2)\subsetneq U\cap(U_1+U_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Can you give me an example that the following inclusion is strict $(U\cap U_1)+(U\cap U_2)\subseteq U\cap(U_1+U_2)$ if $U$ is a vector space and $U_1,U_2$ are subspaces of it.

Both are not necessarily subspaces, but is there a case s.t. RHS is one and LHS is not ?

Comment: I assume you rather mean that $U,U_1,U_2$ are subspaces of a common vector space ($V$, say)?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen I think you can German    http://i.stack.imgur.com/6qlJy.png

Comment: Well, it seems the original problem statement is exactly as you translated it - which means that TZakrevskiy's answer is spot on. (It is an awful problem statement though and I still consider it quite likely that the author did not intend it this way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U$ is a vector space and $U_i$ are its subspaces, then $U_1+U_2$ is also a subspace of $U$. Moreover, $U\cap U_i = U_i$ and $U\cap (U_1+U_2) = U_1+U_2$.

Hence your inclusion essentially writes

$$U_1+U_2\subseteq U_1+U_2,$$
which is always an equality.

Comment: Yes I think the equalities in the  $2^{\text{nd}}$ line should be correct, but $U_1+U_2$ is not always a subspace right ? otherwise this post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71872/union-of-two-vector-subspaces-not-a-subspace is false

Comment: @ketum If $U_i$ are vector spaces, then their sum $U_1+U_2$ is always a vector space (easy to check by definition). However, their union  $U_1\cup U_2$ is not necessarily a vector space.