# Is U union W necessarily a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let U and w be two subspaces of the same vector space V.Is U union W necessarily a vector space?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71872/union-of-two-vector-subspaces-not-a-subspace

Comment: the answer is no, and it's almost impossible not to understand why if you think of a simple example. moreover, this question is a duplicate; it's asked dozens of times on this site. show a little effort.

Comment: Name a 1-dimensional vector space of $\Bbb R^2$. Name another. Is their union a vector space?

Answer (score 0):

Let $V = R^3$. Choose the subspaces to be generated by two non parallel vectors, respectively. Then the sum of the two vectors is not contained in the union.