# Let $V$ be a vector space and $U,W$ be its subspaces. Prove that if the union $U\cup W$ is a subspace of $V$, then $W \subseteq U$ or $U \subseteq W$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and $U,W$ be its subspaces.  Prove that if the union $U\cup W$ is a subspace of $V$, then $W \subseteq U$ or $U \subseteq W$.

I'm not sure where to begin at all really.

Comment: Not following.  If $U$ is a subspace of $V$ then isn't $U\cup V=V$?

Comment: Is it possible you meant $U\cup W$?

Comment: See Timere's and BU982T's answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71872/union-of-two-vector-subspaces-not-a-subspace).

Answer (score 1):

Begin by removing the unnecessary distractions: if $H,K$ are subgroups of a group $(G,\cdot)$ and if $H \cup K$ is also a subgroup of $G$, then $H\subset K$ or $K\subset H$

Proof: suppose $H \not \subset K$. There exists $h \in H -K$. Let $k \in K$. Then $hk \in H \cup K$ but not in $K$, because otherwise $h \in K$. So that $hk \in H$, but then $k \in H$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $U\cup W$ is a subspace.
If $U\subset W$, we are done.
If $U\not\subset W$, there exists $u\in U$ such that $u\notin W$.
Let $w\in W$, we have $w+u\in U \cup W$.
If $w+u\in W$, then $u=(w+u)-w\in W$, a contradiction.
Hence, $w+u \in U$ and thus $w = (w+u)-u \in U$.
It follows that $W\subset U$.

Thanks to [Luca Bressan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/89879/luca-bressan), the proof can be simplified as follow:

Suppose that $U\cup W$ is a subspace.
Let $u\in U$ and $w\in W$, then $w+u\in U \cup W$.
If $w+u\in W$, then $u=(w+u)-w\in W$.
If $w+u \in U$ and thus $w = (w+u)-u \in U$.
It follows that either $W\subset U$ or $U\subset W$.

Comment: You could even remove the assumption $U \not\subset W$ (together with $u \notin W$), and you would still obtain the result from the same argument.

Comment: @LucaBressan I get your point, thanks