# Union of vectorspaces is never a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the union of two different subvectorspaces $U_1,U_2$ of a vectorspace $V$ is in general not a vektor space.

But now I read

> If $U_i$ $(i=1,2)$ has dimension $1$ and $V$ has dimension $2$, the union is never a vectorspace.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: by "union" do you mean $U_1\cup U_2 \cup V$? and are $U_i$ subspaces of $V$ here?

Comment: Just $U_1\cup U_2$.

Comment: But with $U_1 \ne U_2$, I suppose? Otherwise... (note that "_never_" is quite strong).

Comment: Right! Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the case of $V$ being a plane, and $U_i$ representing lines that pass through the origin. Clearly, if you take two vectors from the lines and you add them you will end up with a vector outside the lines, meaning that this is not a vector space.

More formally:

$U_1=\{\alpha(u^{(1)}_1,u^{(2)}_1), \alpha\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $U_2=\{\alpha(u^{(1)}_2,u^{(2)}_2), \alpha\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Let $v =(v^{(1)},v^{(2)})=\alpha(u^{(1)}_1,u^{(2)}_1) + \beta(u^{(1)}_2,u^{(2)}_2)$ for some $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$. If the union were to be a vector space, then there must exist $\gamma \in\mathbb R$ such that $v = \gamma(u^{(1)}_1,u^{(2)}_1)$ or $v = \gamma(u^{(1)}_2,u^{(2)}_2)$.

Solve each of the equations for $\gamma$ and convince yourself that there is no $\gamma\in\mathbb R$ that can can solve them. Therefore the assumption is false and the union cannot be a vector space.

Comment: Not if the lines coincide. Also you might need to explain that $2$-dim vector spaces are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Yes, the lines don't coincide, otherwise it would be trivial and would contradict what we want to prove.

Comment: So this is a geometrically reason which is clear to me, thank to that! But I'd prefer a formal proof.

Comment: @user114179 Please read the more formally written answer. Geometrical reasons are quite formal. If you understand the idea, you can write it as formal as you like, but that's your job.

Answer (score 0):

The union of two subspaces can only be a subspace if one of the subspaces is contained in the other one (e.g. take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/71879/159845)).

Since both subspaces are 1-dimensional and *different*, one can't be contained in the other (why?).