# Linear Algebra: Let U, V be non-zero subspaces of R3, and let W = U ∪ V be the set of vectors which lie in either U or V (or both).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is this statement true or false?
Let U, V be non-zero subspaces of R3, and let W = U ∪ V be the set of vectors which lie in
either U or V (or both). Then W is a subspace of R3
.

Comment: can you share your thoughts/ attempts?

Comment: Here's the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr), and here are some [general tips](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). Thanks for joining our community!

Comment: I attempted to use the closures under vector addition and scalar multiplication to prove that W is a sub space of R. I haven’t learned about spanning sets yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Union of two vector subspaces not a subspace?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71872/union-of-two-vector-subspaces-not-a-subspace)

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take $U$ to be the $x$ axis, and $V$ the $y$ axis. Then $(1,0,0) \in U$, $(0,1,0) \in V$, and clearly their sum is not in $W$.

You need more than the union in this case, since we have additional structure of linearity (i.e. a vector space) on this space. This is also (essentially) answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71872/union-of-two-vector-subspaces-not-a-subspace).

This is also assuming you mean a linear/vector subspace, but I believe that's implicitly assumed in the question.