# The union of two spanning sets

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider three vectors a,b,c they are linear independent with each other. Let P = span{a,b}, Q = span{b,c}. Is the union of P,Q = span{a,b,c}? If not what is it? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Union of two vector subspaces not a subspace?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71872/union-of-two-vector-subspaces-not-a-subspace)

Answer (score 0):

No, take in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the two sets
$$P=span\{\vec{i},\vec{j}\}\text{ and } Q=span\{\vec{j},\vec{k}\}$$
Clearly $P$ Is the $xy-$ plane and $Q$ is the $yz-$ plane so their union is not $\mathbb{R}^3$, where as
$$span\{\vec{i},\vec{j},\vec{k}\}=\mathbb{R}^3$$